# How to make a jQuery popup to ask for logging in or creating profile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I finally got a jQuery popup to work, and now trying to give the user the option to log in or create profile

So far I have something very simple like this:

```
var $dialog = $('<div>Please log-in or create a profile</div>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Login Dialog'
    });
```

But what are some good and simple ways I can ask the person to log in? Should I just make a login form right in the div there? If so, in case the person needs to create a profile instead, how do I easily enable them to do that?

Also, should the login and create-profile code live elsewhere? If so, how do I reference it from this setup?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the login form on your page as inline code. It's much easier to edit that way and switch it to be hidden when you are finished.

e.g.

```
<div id="mypopup" style="display: none;">
  <div id="loginform">
    Login form with layout with controls and buttons
    <span id="newprofile">Click here to create a new profile</span>
  </div>
  <div id="newprofileform" style="display: none;">
    New profile form with layout with controls and buttons
  </div>
</div>
```

And refer to it from your code using its ID.

```
var $dialog = $('#mypopup')
  .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Login Dialog'
  }); 

$("#newprofile").click(function () {
  $("#loginform").hide();
  $("#newprofileform").show();
});
```

Comment: how come you got a -1 vote? I think it was a reasonable answer. By the way, should I make that div not shown during initial page load somehow?

Comment: and how do I swap out the login form and the create profile form?

Comment: Thanks, I dunno why it was donvoted, no comment left. Yes, format and style the div at leisure and add the display:none style when you are finished. This way you make sur eit looks nice before finally hiding it.

Comment: For the create profile form, it depends how complicated the process is going to be. If it's simple, you can use the same approach and just add another div. If it's very complicated you can redirect to a completely new page.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant in the original popup if I ask the person to log in, and provide a link to "create profile" - how do I swap the popup windows to display the other div?  Does my question make sense sort of? :)

Comment: See updated answer for what I mean. Use multiple divs withing the popup and show/hide them as required.